# Import Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, graphql-js

I'm getting an import error that I can't understand. `queries.js` is located inside of my src folder. I'm trying to import it into one of my files that sits inside of the pages folder. I have two periods to so that it looks outside of pages back into the src folder. I was able to resolve this issue by copying the file into it's own folder called graphql. When I import from `../graphql/queries.js`; there is no error anymore. In the past when I got these errors it is usually just a typo but I can't find any here. I'm just learning how to use AWS Amplify and AppSynch and I'm getting this error setting up a test App.

I appreciate any help so that I can better understand the problem here. Thank you for your time!

Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/Edi.js 12:0-44

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../queries.js' in 'C:\Users\nmaka\Documents\Meraki_Home\meraki_app\meraki-app\src\pages
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `queries.js` inside the src directory because it's not there right now

Comment: Sorry for cutting that out on the screenshot. I updated the question to have a complete view of my directory. Pages is not inside of a nested folder. It exist just inside of src. I did try ../../queries.js just to be sure and I got a different error saying that it falls outside of the project src/ directory.

Comment: Move your `queries.js` inside the `src` directory because it's not there right now